# Rails background worker seems to be wrapped in a transaction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job, postgresql-9.2, rails-postgresql

I know how useless and vague the title is. Sorry. I don't have much other than some observation and evidence that nothing changed in my code.

I have a Rails 3.2.14 app using DelayedJob and PostgreSQL 9.2. For months, I have had code that has background workers process file contents into the database. Each job/task will load 100K to 1M records. Until very, very recently, when I would watch the database, I could see the records accumulating by calling `Product.count`, for example.

Now, I only see `Product.count` update to a new sum when a job/task completes. It is almost as if the entire operation is now being wrapped in a transaction preventing me from seeing the incremental changes. I have verified that nothing in the relevant areas of code have changed and I've been on 3.2.14 for some time now.

Does anyone know what this could be? DelayedJob?

I am also using Ruby 2.0.0-p247.

Comment: So what has changed "very very recently"? Have you upgraded anything?

Comment: As near as I can tell, nothing has changed. I can only say that for certainty in the related areas of my code. I most certainly have been able see records get written as the file is processed and now they are only visible when the total operation completes.

Answer (score 0):

From this post `https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/issues/585#issuecomment-56743773`, it appears that delayed_job is not wrapping the job in a transaction.